# I want to see only records which have only the column "C_STATUS" changed

Tags: sql, hana

I have this situation:

The table has more columns. The column "BEGIN_DATE" and "END_DATE" changes everytime there is a change in one field of the record.

```
N_POlICY        BEGIN_DATE              END_DATE                C_STATUS
50.007.267.xxx  29-feb-2012 0.00.00.0   20-nov-2015 0.00.00.0   0
50.007.267.xxx  20-nov-2015 0.00.00.0   24-dic-2015 0.00.00.0   0
50.007.267.xxx  24-dic-2015 0.00.00.0   29-mar-2017 0.00.00.0   0
50.007.267.xxx  29-mar-2017 0.00.00.0   4-lug-2017 0.00.00.0    7
50.007.267.xxx  4-lug-2017 0.00.00.0    29-ago-2017 0.00.00.0   0
50.007.267.xxx  29-ago-2017 0.00.00.0   10-ott-2017 0.00.00.0   7
50.007.267.xxx  10-ott-2017 0.00.00.0   29-mag-2018 0.00.00.0   0
50.007.267.xxx  29-mag-2018 0.00.00.0   10-lug-2018 0.00.00.0   7
50.007.267.xxx  10-lug-2018 0.00.00.0   31-dic-2050 0.00.00.0   0
```

I am trying to develop a select which shows only the records with different status, so only when the status change. The result should be like this:

```
N_POlICY        BEGIN_DATE              END_DATE                C_STATUS
50.007.267.xxx  24-dic-2015 0.00.00.0   29-mar-2017 0.00.00.0   0
50.007.267.xxx  29-mar-2017 0.00.00.0   4-lug-2017 0.00.00.0    7
50.007.267.xxx  4-lug-2017 0.00.00.0    29-ago-2017 0.00.00.0   0
50.007.267.xxx  29-ago-2017 0.00.00.0   10-ott-2017 0.00.00.0   7
50.007.267.xxx  10-ott-2017 0.00.00.0   29-mag-2018 0.00.00.0   0
50.007.267.xxx  29-mag-2018 0.00.00.0   10-lug-2018 0.00.00.0   7
50.007.267.xxx  10-lug-2018 0.00.00.0   31-dic-2050 0.00.00.0   0
```

I've used this query thanks to @Fahmi and the result is this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT  N_POLICY,
        BEGIN_DATE,
        END_DATE,
        C_STATUS,
        LAG(C_STATUS) OVER(PARTITION BY N_POLICY ORDER BY BEGIN_DATE) AS PREV_STATUS
FROM TABLE_NAME
)A WHERE C_STATUS <> PREV_STATUS AND N_POLICY = '50007267xxx'
```

```
N_POlICY        BEGIN_DATE              END_DATE                C_STATUS  PREV_ST
50.007.267.536  29-mar-2017 0.00.00.0   4-lug-2017 0.00.00.0    7          0
50.007.267.536  4-lug-2017 0.00.00.0    29-ago-2017 0.00.00.0   0          7
50.007.267.536  29-ago-2017 0.00.00.0   10-ott-2017 0.00.00.0   7          0
50.007.267.536  10-ott-2017 0.00.00.0   29-mag-2018 0.00.00.0   0          7
50.007.267.536  29-mag-2018 0.00.00.0   10-lug-2018 0.00.00.0   7          0
50.007.267.536  10-lug-2018 0.00.00.0   31-dic-2050 0.00.00.0   0          7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` window function

```
select * from
(
select d_inizio,d_fine,c_statto,lag(c_statto) over(order by d_inizio) as prev_status
from tablename
)A where c_statto<>prev_status
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Fahmi
I've just updated the question after your query, do you have some other tips?

Comment: @NovaDragmatika, where you've got the policy column, it is not in your table according to images

Comment: @NovaDragmatika, could you please make your table structure and provide some sample data here - https://dbfiddle.uk/ it would be easy to answer your question then

Comment: Anyway, the problem now is that i don't see the first record because the where excludes the first value

Comment: I didn't invalidate any answer. I've just formatted in a more comprehensible way the data sample. The answer of Fahmi doesn't fullfill completely the question. Thanks anyway.